# how do I run two sites on the same server with SSL

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate

I've a site which is running on IIS with SSL port 443 (development server)
I want to add one more website which'll use SSL, how do I do it? I used a different port (444) but not able to access the site by a different team in our organization (they can access the site if it's not ssl enabled and the site which is SSL enabled already on the server)
Any idea?
we are using windows server 2003 R2

Comment: get another ip and bind 443 with that domain on that ip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most web browsers have problems connecting to SSL-enabled servers on non standard port, have you tried entering "https" explicitly? For example:

```
https://server.site.tld:444/project
```

Comment: yes, I have tried with https, I'm able to access it within our group, different team at different location not able to access it.

Comment: are they using the same browser?

Comment: yes, they are using IE

Comment: and the same version? If yes, it looks more like a firewall issue to me. Ask them to use telnet to check if the port's accessible.